# Listing All JIRA Transitions via API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm looking to set up smart commits in JIRA, but my developers want to know all the options for their transitions.  In order to help them, I'd like to print a cheat-sheet of all transition names (I trust they are smart enough to figure out what does what from there).

But when I look through the REST API documentation, I can only find a way to get the [list of transitions for a particular issue](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e797) (presumably via its status).  Is there a way to get the list of *all* transitions that any ticket can take at any point in its workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all transitions for project with [/rest/api/2/project/{projectIdOrKey}/statuses](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/project-getAllStatuses) endpoint. Here is response example, look at "statuses" array:

```
[
    {
        "self": "http://localhost:8090/jira/rest/api/2.0/issueType/3",
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Task",
        "subtask": false,
        "statuses": [
            {
                "self": "http://localhost:8090/jira/rest/api/2.0/status/10000",
                "description": "The issue is currently being worked on.",
                "iconUrl": "http://localhost:8090/jira/images/icons/progress.gif",
                "name": "In Progress",
                "id": "10000"
            },
            {
                "self": "http://localhost:8090/jira/rest/api/2.0/status/5",
                "description": "The issue is closed.",
                "iconUrl": "http://localhost:8090/jira/images/icons/closed.gif",
                "name": "Closed",
                "id": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But it doesn't give you exactly list of transitions that any issue can take at any time, and I'm not sure that such method exist in API.

Comment: But it is not transitions - it is statuses. Transition name - it is name of action to move issue from one status to another.

Answer (score 10):

You can list the transitions of a given ticket via this endpoint:

```
/rest/api/2/issue/${issueIdOrKey}/transitions
```

For a more in depth explanation take a look here:
[Does the JIRA REST API require submitting a transition ID when transitioning an issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738782/does-the-jira-rest-api-require-submitting-a-transition-id-when-transitioning-an)

Comment: This only shows the transitions available from the current state of the selected issue. Sometimes this is what you need, but it's not the list of all transitions (or all statuses) in the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void changeStatus(IssueRestClient iRestClient,
        List<Statuses> JiraStatuses, String key) {
    String status = "To Do";
    for (Statuses statuses : vOneToJiraStatuses) {
        if (1 == statuses.compareTo(status)) {
            try {
                String _transition = statuses.getTransition();
                Issue issue = iRestClient.getIssue(key).get();
                Transition transition = getTransition(iRestClient, issue,
                        _transition);
                if (!(isBlankOrNull(transition))) {

                    if (!(issue.getStatus().getName()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(_transition)))
                        transition(transition, issue, null, iRestClient,
                                status);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Constants.ERROR.info(Level.INFO, e);

            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

List is a pojo implementation where statuses and transitions defined in xml are injected through setter/constructor.

```
private void transition(Transition transition, Issue issue,
        FieldInput fieldInput, IssueRestClient issueRestClient,
        String status) throws Exception {

    if (isBlankOrNull(fieldInput)) {
        TransitionInput transitionInput = new TransitionInput(
                transition.getId());

                issueRestClient.transition(issue, transitionInput).claim();
        Constants.REPORT.info("Status Updated for : " + issue.getKey());
    } else {
        TransitionInput transitionInput = new TransitionInput(
                transition.getId());
        issueRestClient.transition(issue, transitionInput).claim();
        Constants.REPORT.info("Status Updated for : " + issue.getKey());

    }
}

public Transition getTransition(IssueRestClient issueRestClient,
        Issue issue, String _transition) {

        Promise<Iterable<Transition>> ptransitions = issueRestClient
            .getTransitions(issue);
    Iterable<Transition> transitions = ptransitions.claim();
    for (Transition transition : transitions) {

        if (transition.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(_transition)) {
            return transition;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In Short using Transition API of JIRA we can fetch all the transitions to set statuses